# How do I perform p-value correction for kruskal-wallis testing with Scipy?

Tags: scipy, statistics, p-value, adjustment, kruskal-wallis

I saw that scipy.stats.mstats.kruskalwallis returns only,
 1. statistic
 2. pvalue

How do I extract pvalues for correction?

Or, is there any other ways I can perform k-w testing and correction, with python?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "correction"? Are you trying to perform a post-hoc test for differences between particular pairs of groups?

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Yeah, I want to perform FDR or BH control.